# Is there way to stop ads?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, ads

Every time I unlock my phone (yu yunicorn | marshmallow), ad pops up, covering the whole screen, ads also pop ups when I am using any app and it also uses chrome to direct to ads, its poping up when I am writing this, is there a way to stop these ads ?( disabling the internet is one way, I think, but I want to be connected all times)

Comment: Use [Lucky Patcher](https://lucky-patcher.netbew.com/).

Comment: @iBug Lucky Patcher is quite tricky to use, if the goal is removing ads. Won't something such as AdAway be equally effective or better?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman It can easily remove most common ads by adding 60k+ lines in the hosts file. Not so tricky this way.

Comment: @iBug It has quite evolved since I last used it, heh. By the way, certain custom ROMs block it.

Comment: I scanned with Dr.Web.... There is a threat named as ' not a virus adware (adware)' and when I am going for options, it is giving only option as 'ignore' not to 'delete' or 'quarantine' as other threats. Message appears that it is a file from system and only option to ignore. It says 'the standard neutralizing actions are not applicable for system applications'

Comment: Probably it needs root access. Never install stuffs outside playstore unless you trust the developer who created the app.

Comment: Which app it is? If it is a system app you can, without root, block it from running. Let us know the precise results.

Comment: @firelord Named as 'rockclient.apk' but I can't find in apps

Comment: Do you have an app named "Gmobi" or "System update"? If yes, use [AppXplore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonyericsson.androidapp.AppExplore&hl=en) to give us the package name. Try to post the screenshot please.

Comment: I used 'addons Detector' suggested by @acejavelin, it showed the all the names of files that comes with any app. It has a search option in which I used to search 'leadbolt' ( as I noticed in one of the corners of a ad), and it was 'u torrent pro' that I downloaded from web and installed

Comment: I also scanned with Dr.Web as suggested by @Rajedran Nadar before and after using 'addons Detector' ,which showed me 'u torrent pro' as threat. Thanks to Everyone for helping.

Comment: @iBug next time I'll try lucky patcher. ( I hope I won't need to ) thanks

Comment: Always remeber check permission before you install any app..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These type of ads usually come from an app you have installed, typically uninstalling the offending app will correct this.

Use [Addons Detector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.denper.addonsdetector) to determine the app that is causing the ads and uninstall it.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Dr. Web](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.drweb) (You can use any antivirus but this worked for me) application from play store.

Let the application scan your mobile phone. It will detect and remove all the adware from you phone. I tried and this worked for me.